# "There was a problem with reindexing process" after upgrade?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, database, upgrade

I'm facing a problem with reindexing **Product Prices** after upgrading magento.

Previously I used the magento `1.7.0.2` version. It was working fine in live. Then for upgradation purpose, I installed the recent Magento version `1.9.1.1` using the database used for the old version magento.

It got upgraded. But after installation, it asked for reindexing, and there was **Product Prices** indexing only seen on red in color. I tried to reindexing that. But it shows the error **There was a problem with reindexing process**.

Then I saw in exception.log, It shows the following error

```
2015-06-03T04:09:20+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND tad_special_from_date.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `t' at line 16, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx` SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, `cg`.`customer_group_id`, `cw`.`website_id`, IF(IFNULL(tas_tax_class_id.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_tax_class_id.value, tad_tax_class_id.value) AS `tax_class_id`, ta_price.value AS `orig_price`, IF(IF(gp.price IS NULL, ta_price.value, gp.price) < IF(IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value)) <= DATE(cwd.website_date), 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value)) >= DATE(cwd.website_date), 1, 0)) > 0 AND ta_special_price.value < ta_price.value, ta_special_price.value, ta_price.value), IF(gp.price IS NULL, ta_price.value, gp.price), IF(IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value)) <= DATE(cwd.website_date), 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value)) >= DATE(cwd.website_date), 1, 0)) > 0 AND ta_special_price.value < ta_price.value, ta_special_price.value, ta_price.value)) AS `price`, IF(IF(gp.price IS NULL, ta_price.value, gp.price) < IF(IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value)) <= DATE(cwd.website_date), 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value)) >= DATE(cwd.website_date), 1, 0)) > 0 AND ta_special_price.value < ta_price.value, ta_special_price.value, ta_price.value), IF(gp.price IS NULL, ta_price.value, gp.price), IF(IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value)) <= DATE(cwd.website_date), 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value)) >= DATE(cwd.website_date), 1, 0)) > 0 AND ta_special_price.value < ta_price.value, ta_special_price.value, ta_price.value)) AS `min_price`, IF(IF(gp.price IS NULL, ta_price.value, gp.price) < IF(IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value)) <= DATE(cwd.website_date), 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value)) >= DATE(cwd.website_date), 1, 0)) > 0 AND ta_special_price.value < ta_price.value, ta_special_price.value, ta_price.value), IF(gp.price IS NULL, ta_price.value, gp.price), IF(IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value)) <= DATE(cwd.website_date), 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value)) >= DATE(cwd.website_date), 1, 0)) > 0 AND ta_special_price.value < ta_price.value, ta_special_price.value, ta_price.value)) AS `max_price`, tp.min_price AS `tier_price`, tp.min_price AS `base_tier`, gp.price AS `group_price`, gp.price AS `base_group_price` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 CROSS JOIN `customer_group` AS `cg`
 CROSS JOIN `core_website` AS `cw`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_website` AS `cwd` ON cw.website_id = cwd.website_id
 INNER JOIN `core_store_group` AS `csg` ON csg.website_id = cw.website_id AND cw.default_group_id = csg.group_id
 INNER JOIN `core_store` AS `cs` ON csg.default_store_id = cs.store_id AND cs.store_id != 0
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `pw` ON pw.product_id = e.entity_id AND pw.website_id = cw.website_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_index_tier_price` AS `tp` ON tp.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tp.website_id = cw.website_id AND tp.customer_group_id = cg.customer_group_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_index_group_price` AS `gp` ON gp.entity_id = e.entity_id AND gp.website_id = cw.website_id AND gp.customer_group_id = cg.customer_group_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tad_status` ON tad_status.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_status.attribute_id = 96 AND tad_status.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_status` ON tas_status.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_status.attribute_id = 96 AND tas_status.store_id = cs.store_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tad_tax_class_id` ON tad_tax_class_id.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_tax_class_id.attribute_id = 122 AND tad_tax_class_id.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_tax_class_id` ON tas_tax_class_id.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_tax_class_id.attribute_id = 122 AND tas_tax_class_id.store_id = cs.store_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `ta_price` ON ta_price.entity_id = e.entity_id AND ta_price.attribute_id = 75 AND ta_price.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `ta_special_price` ON ta_special_price.entity_id = e.entity_id AND ta_special_price.attribute_id = 76 AND ta_special_price.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `tad_special_from_date` ON tad_special_from_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_special_from_date.attribute_id =  AND tad_special_from_date.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `tas_special_from_date` ON tas_special_from_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_special_from_date.attribute_id =  AND tas_special_from_date.store_id = cs.store_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `tad_special_to_date` ON tad_special_to_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_special_to_date.attribute_id = 78 AND tad_special_to_date.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `tas_special_to_date` ON tas_special_to_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_special_to_date.attribute_id = 78 AND tas_special_to_date.store_id = cs.store_id
 INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `ciss` ON ciss.product_id = e.entity_id AND ciss.website_id = cw.website_id WHERE (e.type_id = 'downloadable') AND (IF(IFNULL(tas_status.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_status.value, tad_status.value)=1) AND (ciss.stock_status = 1)
Trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/dbrepair/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/dbrepair/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/dbrepair/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/dbrepair/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/dbrepair/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/dbrepair/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Default.php(287): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#6 /opt/lampp/htdocs/dbrepair/app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/Resource/Indexer/Price.php(47): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Default->_prepareFinalPriceData()
#7 /opt/lampp/htdocs/dbrepair/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(385): Mage_Downloadable_Model_Resource_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#8 /opt/lampp/htdocs/dbrepair/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#9 /opt/lampp/htdocs/dbrepair/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#10 /opt/lampp/htdocs/dbrepair/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#11 /opt/lampp/htdocs/dbrepair/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(127): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#12 /opt/lampp/htdocs/dbrepair/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->reindexProcessAction()
#13 /opt/lampp/htdocs/dbrepair/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('reindexProcess')
#14 /opt/lampp/htdocs/dbrepair/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#15 /opt/lampp/htdocs/dbrepair/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(348): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#16 /opt/lampp/htdocs/dbrepair/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#17 /opt/lampp/htdocs/dbrepair/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#18 {main}
```

I tried with db repair tool. But It does not help me. Then I tried clearing some log tables too. Nothing helped me.

I'm not familiar with magento database structure. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What modifications do you have in app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/App.php. I suggest doing a diff to app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php

Comment: There is no problem with files, Because I checked this by connecting a fresh magento 1.9 versioned db with the same files. That was working fine.

Comment: Just going on a hunch, but the stack trace references downloadable products. Does your store have downloadable products? If not, this seems like a possible exploit tactic on a hacked site. If it does use downloadable products, then I'm not sure. It seems odd that this would happen on a clean install.

Comment: These two is specifically the problem lines. Looks to me like it cant get an attribute ID for special price from date. Have you perhaps had something installed which has removed those?
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `tad_special_from_date` ON tad_special_from_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_special_from_date.attribute_id =  AND tad_special_from_date.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `tas_special_from_date` ON tas_special_from_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_special_from_date.attribute_id =  AND tas_special_from_date.store_id = cs.store_id

Comment: Did you clear you cache and locks directory from your var folder?

Comment: I came across the same/similar problem after adding a new customer group.  I simply added a customer to this group and indexing started to work again.